# iTerm2 - sometimes copy color, sometimes copy without color?

Tags: iterm, copy-paste

I use iTerm2 and love it.
However, sometimes I want to copy text with color, and sometimes I don't.

I typically paste into Mail. In previous versions I got color always, but then perhaps I changed a preference?

The problem with pasting with no style is that I *want* pasting to include the font (fixed), I just don't want the color.

Is there a way to set up iTerm 2 so that I have a choice?

Comment: It's usually at the point of paste you make that call; paste without style [or paste & match style] is available in many apps. Which app are you pasting to?

Comment: @Tetsujin - I expanded the question to answer yours.

Answer (score 2):

When you copy in iTerm, use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy with color and style, and use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy without style.

Comment: But I want the font size, just not the cooor…

Comment: @vy32 mine will copy the "style", including the font size.